# creating an empty state object that has a key value array with JSON objects as the values and than changing those json objects

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am attempting to create a reactJS state that has an empty array in it on construction. Once i receive a message, that is a JSON object, I would want to create a key in that array and store that received message as the value under that key.

for example. I have

array x =[]

JSON_obj = {"data":"mydata"}

in normal javascript I could say

x["some_key"] = JSON_obj

I am attempting accomplish this in reactJS inside the state.

```js
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      cusipData: []
    };

    this.socket = io("adresss");

    this.socket.on("ringBuffer", function(data) {
      addMessage(JSON.parse(data));
    });

    const addMessage = data => {
      this.setState({ cusipData: this.state.cusipData[data.cusip], data });

      console.log("this.state");
      console.log(this.state);
    };
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be careful with using `setState` when self-referencing `this.state` in the method as state should remain immutable. This should work.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      cusipData: []
    };

    this.socket = io("adresss");

    this.socket.on("ringBuffer", function(data) {
      addMessage(JSON.parse(data));
    });

    const addMessage = data => {
      this.setState((prevState, props) => {
        const newCusipData = prevState.cusipData;
        newCusipData[data.cusip] = data;

        return {
          cusipData: newCusipData
        };
      });

      console.log("this.state");
      console.log(this.state);
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: @SteveBohmbach No problem. If this is solved, can you mark it as well for others looking to accomplish the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

The following method `addMessage` adds the `data.cusip` parameter to the existing `state.cusipData` array.

```js
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props)
  {
    super(props)
    
    this.state = {
      cusipData: [],
    };

    this.socket = io("adresss")

    this.socket.on('ringBuffer', function(data){
        addMessage(JSON.parse(data));
    });

    const addMessage = data => {
      // adds the new data.cusip to the existing state array
      this.setState({
        cusipData: [...this.state.cusipData, data.cusip]
      });
    };
  }
```

Comment: I needed to add if not there, and update if it already exsists